# How do I restrict AWS instances by user group in the AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In an AWS environment, I have both dev and production instances, AWS users who belong to the "developer" group should only see the dev instances, however users from the "admin" group should see all instances. How do I make it so that everybody sees what what they have access to in the AWS console?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create IAM policies to allow access to only specific instances.  This would require IAM policies along the lines of:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1404698512098",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/i-123456"
    }
  ]
}
```

This above policy would allow the user it is applied to full access to all EC2 commands on the instance i-123456. You should read through the documentation on [IAM Policies for EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html) to make sure you fully understand all the available EC2 actions, conditions, etc.

Managing policies like this can quickly become quite complex if you are trying to completely isolate resources to specific groups.  Your IAM policies will quickly become quite complex if you start using other AWS resources than just EC2, or even if you are just launching and terminating large numbers of EC2 instances. If you are using services other than EC2 then you will need to read up on how IAM works with each of those services and create policies for each service to restrict access within each as necessary.

You might want to consider another approach to segregating users, which our company has been using for a few years now.  We actually have 5 different AWS accounts, and each account is used for different purposes.  For example, one account is for developers so they can test whatever they want and it's no big deal if they break something.  Another account is for our corporate IT department, and the IT department uses it to provide services to the company like our wiki, etc. Other AWS accounts are for various production environments that we have.  The only people who have access to all these accounts are our senior AWS admins.  Access is provided to other people only as needed, and IAM is used within each environment to further restrict access only if necessary. We further make use of [Amazon's consolidated billing service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html) to link all the accounts together so that they're effectively one big account as far as Amazon is concerned. This has made our management of AWS resources much easier since we don't have to try to create and manage multiple IAM policies across all the AWS services we use.